# functional analysis on distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I was just looking for a sequence $\{f_{n}\}\subset C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ of smooth functions of commpact support on $R$ and a smooth $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})-C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ of not compact support such that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\{|f_{n}^{(k)}(x)-f^{(k)}(x)|\rightarrow 0$.

I took a function 
$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      -1 & -1\leq x\leq -\frac{1}{n} \\
      nx & -\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{n}\\
      1 & \frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 1 \\
0 &|x|>1
   \end{cases}
$$
 and 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & -1\leq x\leq 1 \\
      1 & |x|>1 \\
     \end{cases}
$$
where $f_{n}$ have compact support $[-1,1]$ and $f$ have no compact support and meeting the requirement.
Is my example correct. I'm not so sure on the smoothness condition stated. 
Thank you

Comment: These functions are certainly not smooth.

Comment: To construct smooth functions with compact support, you need to build bump functions out of $e^{-{1\over x^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a start: Suppose $g \in C(\mathbb R),$ with $g=1$ on $[-1,1],$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $|x|\ge 2.$ Let $f\in C_0(\mathbb R).$ Can you show $[1-g(x/n)]f(x) \to 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R?$